# Installing Composer: command-line PHP list empty

Tags: composer-php

I must be retarded but following [Composer's Windows install doc](https://getcomposer.org/download/), no matter from which folder I run `Composer-Setup.exe`,the "command-line PHP" list remains empty and I can't go through the install process.

There's a `file browser` button but I have absolutely no idea what to pick. Any suggestion?

I also tried the Command-line installation, to no avail. The first line (php -r "copy(`'https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`) gives this error: `bash: command not found`

So I can't install Composer either way...

Comment: Did you install PHP? If not you have to install PHP first! See also https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements

Comment: Well I'm running the install from a folder located within my Apache tree so I do have PHP no? :/

Comment: This depends on your source where you downloaded Apache. Apache does not automatically come with PHP. If you used a bundle like e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) you probably installed PHP too. Look for a `php.exe` on your computer. If you don't have one you don't have PHP. If you don't, install [PHP](http://www.php.net) or use a bundle like XAMPP instead, which comes with Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Pearl and more.

Comment: I did install a bundle and I do have a php.exe, yet I still get bash: command not found...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows Command Line run `echo %PATH%` to see if the path to your `php.exe` is in the environment variable `%PATH%`.

E.g. if your path to PHP is `C:\your\wamp\path\php\php.exe` then `C:\your\wamp\path\php` should show up in `%PATH%`.

You can add a path by either

- running `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\wamp\path\php` in command line.

or

- Open "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path" and add your path to PHP here. Restart any console windows after that or logoff and login again.